# How to sync stored Skype conversations between machines?

Tags: windows-7, skype

Skype stores recent IM conversations on the local machine.  I find this very inconvenient when I have a Skype conversation with someone on my work machine, get home, and the history of that conversation is no longer available.

Is there some tool that can sync conversation histories, for the same account, between two or more installations of Skype on different machines?  Or must I write one myself?

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know where the Skype conversations are stored, it's a simple matter to synchronize them betweeen machines using a tool such as [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en). I use it for synchronizing all manner of files, documents, logs, etc. between my work laptop, my home laptop, my desktop, and my server. It falls into (for me) the "mandatory install on new computer" category.

For your purposes, you could use a flash drive as an intermediary transport.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for Linux using Dropbox: http://blog.andreaolivato.net/open-source/sync-skype-chronologies-using-dropbox.html You didn't write which OS you're using but the approach should also work on Windows and Mac OS. Check the [Dropbox-Wiki](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/SyncOtherFolders) for details.

Answer (score 0):

http://raanan.com/2009/06/22/sync-skype-on-multiple-machines-with-dropbox/

Good tut, with usefull comments as well.

Comment: Can you please summarise the post here. If the link ever goes dark then the answer will become useless.

Comment: Short summary - put the skype convos folder into your dropbox, and make it sync across your computers.