# Skype echoing old IM conversations

Tags: skype

When I open up Skype on one computer, it often echoes old IM conversations that I had on another computer. Does anyone know how to fix this up?

Comment: Echoes? As in you hear old conversations that you had?

Comment: that's weird....sorry i have no idea

Comment: @Randolph: I should clarify. It echos old IM, not voice conversations

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps clear your IM history cache?

> Tools/Options/Privacy and click on Clear Chat History.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is down to Skype's attempted syncing of chat history - see this question on the skype: [Old messages keep coming when I launch Skype from other desktop workstation](https://jira.skype.com/browse/SCW-2458).

You could set up the sync correctly using Dropbox and SyncToy as suggested on the [How to sync stored Skype conversations between machines?](https://superuser.com/q/175230/41494) question on this site.